# find :all -- IN condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models in my rails application: Book and Editions. A book can have many editions.

I need to get all the 'editions' of the 'books' written by a specific author.

**Find all books by a specific author**

```
 @saved_books = Book.find :all, :conditions => ["aut_fk = ?",@aut.id ]
```

@saved_books contains an array of books written by a specific author.

My question is how do i get the editions of the books written by a specific author.

```
@editions =  Edition.find(:all, :conditions => [ "book_fk IN (?)", @saved_book.id]) //this code is not correct
```

Any suggestion is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the code below and it seems to do the job. Hope it might be of help to somebody else

```
@edition =  Edition.find(:all, :conditions => ["book_fk IN (?)", @saved_books.map{|b| b.id}])
```

Comment: Ok, make sense, doing `@saved_books.id` dind't make any sense now that I think about it, since the id method you need is that of every item of the array and not the id method of the array (which I don't know if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?:

```
@edition =  Edition.where(:book_fk => @saved_book.id])
```

**Edit**
Is @saved_book.id an array? It doesn't look like it.
If @saved_book should be @saved_books, then the code would change to:

```
@edition =  Edition.where(:book_fk => @saved_books.map {|b| b.id}])
```

I think...

Comment: I just tried id but it does not seem to work, am getting 'undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x55c0e18>'  Yes @saved_book is an array - yes you are right, i should have renamed it to @saved_books

Comment: undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x56d8cb8>

Comment: Thanks for the '@saved_books.map {|b| b.id}' suggestion mate